# Theme from the short-lived series "Girls Club"

Tags: soundtrack, girls-club

What was the theme song in David E. Kelley's short-lived TV series Girls Club? According to Wikipedia the opening theme is "San Francisco (Be Sure to Wear Flowers in Your Hair)" by Laura Dawn", but this is not the song that played in the promos or the series opening.

Comment: I wonder if this question should actually be closed and a new question created. The question was originally about the theme for Girls Club, and it seems apparent from all sources online that the theme was _either_ San Francisco or Wild (as suggested by @rumandwrite).

Given that, perhaps a new question should be opened asking _specifically_ for the promo music, since technically this question has been answered.

Comment: I don't mind it if its closed. I can post another one if I ever recall additional details. I am fairly certain though, that the song was used as the theme as well, contrary to what online sources say.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know what the procedure is and it's one of these rare cases where all the online sources may well be wrong, given how short-lived and unsuccessful the show was - meaning this question may or may not be correctly answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identifying the song doesn't contribute to understanding the scene.

Answer (score 2):

It's '[**Wild**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAI__h-Bxzo)' by [Poe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ann_Danielewski).

[image: Girls Club - TV Series - Credits]

<sup>*~ Page extract from [Encyclopedia of Television Law Shows by Hal Erickson](http://tinyurl.com/ooc6v3o)*</sup>

Comment: This is *definitely* not the song that actually played. Even a different edit/remix wouldn't sound like it. I remember a distinct, elongated, higher pitch portions that are not in Poe's Wild.

Comment: Fair enough. But rather than getting into a guessing game, it would be best to actually see/hear what you watched. Could you post a video or audio clip of the theme in question?

Comment: I wish. I am trying to find it. The only thing I have to go by is me remembering what it sounds like. :(

Comment: No problem. While we're on the subject, @AndrewMartin has also posted an answer on this page. Does that song he suggested ring any bells? :-)

Comment: The poster in the IMDB thread is correct in saying that it is a female voice... so definitely not the Goo Goo Dolls.

Comment: Got it. Also, try and recollect any of the lyrics (if you can) and edit that bit into your post. It'll help in pinning down the song.

Comment: Until we get some solid leads, here's a guess: [Walk the Walk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEEunvd7ZX8), again by Poe. Well, not exactly a guess since [this](http://www.sputnikmusic.com/review/32853/Poe-Haunted/)  page says that the track was slated to be the theme song for the series.

Comment: I went through Poe's entire album. Her voice, styling, etc don't match it at all. Given that I myself have very little to go on, I'll update this once I recall something new.

Comment: Cool. Looking forward to your update :-) Even if you can't remember the lyrics, it'll help if you could describe the style/genre of the song (while editing the info into your original post). Did it sound like pop/pop-rock/electronica? As mentioned earlier, the more you describe it the more it'll help us identify the song.

Answer (score 0):

I've *never* seen the show, or any of its promos - and given it lasted just two episodes it's proving difficult to actually find a link to it anywhere.

You've already ruled out [Laura Dawn - San Franciso](http://www.filminamerica.com/Movies/GirlsClub/girls-club.mp3), but that does seem to be listed in most places as the theme.

Over at the IMDB, somebody [asked a question](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0316984/board/nest/112934?ref_=tt_bd_1) regarding the song that appeared in the commercials, with the answer given as [The Goo Goo Dolls - Here is Gone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bo2iGkS0pRY).

I can't find anything else to substantiate this, but I'll post it as a possible answer. Is this song what you're looking for?

Comment: Not Goo Goo Dolls for sure. As mentioned in that thread, it's definitely a female voice and the song was used for both the promos and the theme.

Comment: And it's definitely not the Laura Dawn theme I've posted. I know you said earlier no, but I just want to double check as I can find no other references to the short-lived show online.

Comment: @RecursiveCall: Forgot to address you in previous post (so not sure if it alerted you). Is it _definitely_ not the Laura Dawn theme?

Comment: It's definitely not a variation of San Francisco. The song you linked above may have been played in one of the scenes but not as a promo/theme. Perhaps Fox swapped it out for whatever reason.